# Hamming distance understanding issue

Tags: hamming-distance

I'm currently trying to understand the hamming code - or specifically the hamming distance for detecting and repairing wrong bits. [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance/)

I have a hard time understanding the hamming distance.  I know I am comparing different words of bits and find the number of bits that make the words different (->hamming distance) - but what are this words I am comparing?

For example: word= 0110 1001 -> (even) parity bits added at end: 0110 (first parity checks bit1-4, 2nd 5-8, 3rd 3,4,5,6, 4th 0,1,7,8).
=> makes the (new)word: 0110 0001 0110.

am i now checking the words with the parity bits?  word1: 0110 0 (bit 1-4 + parity-bit 1). word2: 0001 1 (bit 5-8 + parity-bit 2). word3: 1000 1 (bit 3,4,5,6, + parity bit 3). word4: 0101 0 (bit 0,1,7,8 + parity bit 4).

word1->word2: hamming distance 4. word2->word3: hamming distance 3. word3->word4: hamming distance 4

or am I completely wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be (and from your description *are*) using the Hamming Code, not Hamming Distance. They are different things. As for checking the errors, from Wikipedia on [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#Hamming_codes):

> To check for errors, check all of the parity bits. The pattern of
>   errors, called the error syndrome, identifies the bit in error. If all
>   parity bits are correct, there is no error. Otherwise, the sum of the
>   positions of the erroneous parity bits identifies the erroneous bit.
>   For example, if the parity bits in positions 1, 2 and 8 indicate an
>   error, then bit 1+2+8=11 is in error. If only one parity bit indicates
>   an error, the parity bit itself is in error.

The role of the Hamming distance in the Hamming code is a way to explain why a Hamming Code can only correct 1 bit and detect 2 bits of errors. By applying a Hamming Code all valid word are separated by a hamming distance of 3. Any fault that flips 1 bit will result in a word that is 1-hamming distance away from the correct word. It can be corrected by going to the nearest correct word. Any fault that flips 2 bits will results in a word that is 2 hamming distances away from the correct word, but also 2 hamming distances from another correct word. As such only 2 faults can be detected. As all correct words are 3 distances apart, faults of 3 or more bits can't be detected.

Comment: no problem. Added a little explanation about the use of the Hamming Distance in relation to the hamming code.